# How to add a uid from a shell script?

Tags: shell, gnupg, pgp

I have gnupg 1.4.10 (sorry, no `gpg2`, no `--quick-add-uid`) and like to add a uid to a key from a shell script. I know about `adduid`, but it seems to work interactively only. How would I do this from a shell script? TIA!

Bonus points: And how to remove/revoke a uid using a script?

Comment: Generally, if you need to do something GnuPG doesn't make easy to automate, your options are (1) to do something hacky with expect, or (2) use a different OpenPGP implementation already. I strongly recommend the latter -- if you know Golang, the x/crypto/openpgp library is great and easy to use, and *much* less trouble than its GnuPG-backed alternatives such as python-gnupg. And maintaining automation for GnuPG across version changes is unpleasant.

Comment: (If it were easy to do what you want without `--quick-add-uid`, what point would there have been to adding `--quick-add-uid`?)

Comment: Thanks, Charles. The system is relatively old and it is not very easy to add new software. So, no golang, no expect. But there is Python and it should be possible to add python-pexpect at least. With that it should be possible.

Comment: Actually, software written in Go compiles to static binaries; it's particularly easy to install on old systems (doesn't care what your libc version is, doesn't need any other libraries; just scp the one compiled executable over and run).